# What designates the default shipping on one-page checkout?

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I am implementing my own custom shipping carrier that gives you five free options for shipping.  I need to be able to set the default selected shipping based on the order.

I found where in the one-page checkout the default shipping is being set:

```
<input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?> class="radio"/>
```

`$this->getAddressShippingMethod()` is set to `callcenter_ccshipping_firstclass` - an awfully specific shipping method.  I discover that `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available::getAddressShippingMethod()` is actually just using `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::getShippingMethod()` - a model method.

But here is where I get totally lost - I'm not exactly sure what is involved in setting the default shipping method, or why it selected `callcenter_ccshipping_firstclass`.  There are lots of promising leads, mentions of `setShippingMethod()` several places in the code, but I'm not sure which place is the correct place to look at, and there's just enough indirection going on to make things confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally answered my own question - there is no such thing as a 'default shipping method'.  What I discovered is that Magento reuses the same quote over and over again, and I had selected a shipping method many moons ago, and even if I abandon my checkout procedure and empty the cart, the quote sticks around with the shipping method I had selected.  When I actually delete the quote and get a fresh one, there is no default shipping method selected.